# Incorrect Join in a View

Tags: sql, t-sql, view

I am creating a View in SQL Manager 2012 that has some Employee Details (name, costcenter, etc). 
The Cost Centers that are labeled in the master report are more detailed than i need (however, I will need that info in the future so I don't want to remove it). I created a table that has all of the Cost Centers with a Basic Label.

I added the Main Employee Table to the View then added the Cost Center Label table to the view. I connected the CostCenterNo from the Employee Table to the CostCenterNo in the Label table. I selected the Label name to be viewed instead of the Main Label from the employee table.

The problem is when I run the connection it duplicated several of the rows, going from 400+ to over 1200 rows. All I want to do is replace the complex label with a simple label for reporting.

Here is the code in the View.

```
SELECT        dbo.EEMasterData.EmpNo, dbo.EEMasterData.EmpName,
dbo.EEMasterData.JobNo, dbo.EEMasterData.JobName, dbo.EEMasterData.OrgUnit,
dbo.EEMasterData.OrgName, dbo.EEMasterData.PArea,  
dbo.EEMasterData.PSubAreaNo,dbo.EEMasterData.PSubAreaName, 
dbo.EEMasterData.MasterCCNo,dbo.CostCenterConsolidatedLkUp.CostCenterMain, 
dbo.EEMasterData.PositionNo, dbo.EEMasterData.PositionName, 
dbo.EEMasterData.EmpGroupNo, dbo.EEMasterData.EmpGroupName, 
dbo.EEMasterData.EmpSubGroupNo, dbo.EEMasterData.EmpSubGroupName, 
dbo.EEMasterData.StartDate, dbo.EEMasterData.EndDate, dbo.EEMasterData.Status, 
dbo.EEMasterData.EmpStatus
FROM            dbo.CostCenterConsolidatedLkUp INNER JOIN
                     dbo.EEMasterData ON 
dbo.CostCenterConsolidatedLkUp.CostCenterMainNo = dbo.EEMasterData.MasterCCNo
```

I think the Join is what is causing the duplication but it wont let me change the join in the view designer.

Does anyone know how to change the join or is there a better way to add this label. There are approximately 100+ cost centers so coding would be tedious, this is why I am trying to do it through the view. (I'm on a short timetable, sorry).

Comment: Change your `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT` and rerun the query. If you still have 1200 result rows, then you need to rethink what you are asking and decide which 400 of those you actually want.

Comment: @Anon distinct is not a prober way of resolving a join issue

Comment: I believe this is a problem with the Join. It currently only allows me to do an Inner Join. I tried to type over it and do an Outer join but when I ran the query again it gave me an error.

Comment: so which info do you want when there are more matches in dbo.CostCenterConsolidatedLkUp

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I'm recommending trying DISTINCT to point out that this isn't a JOIN issue, it's a "first decide what you want the query to produce" issue. There are multiple CostCenterMainNo matching each MasterCCNo, but Brian only wants one of them.  The open question is: which one?

Comment: I basically want to Add a column to the view that displays the simple name  from the CostCenterlkup for the cost centers that already exist in the EEMaster, nothing more.

Comment: @Anon we agree, the issue is which row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the correct number of rows. It will give you a more or less random value for CostCenterMain from CostCenterConsolidatedLkUp.

You need sqlserver 2005+

```
SELECT e.EmpNo, e.EmpName,
e.JobNo, e.JobName, 
e.OrgUnit,
e.OrgName, 
e.PArea,  
e.PSubAreaNo,
e.PSubAreaName, 
e.MasterCCNo,
c.CostCenterMain, 
e.PositionNo, 
e.PositionName, 
e.EmpGroupNo, 
e.EmpGroupName, 
e.EmpSubGroupNo, 
e.EmpSubGroupName, 
e.StartDate, 
e.EndDate, 
e.Status, 
e.EmpStatus
FROM dbo.EEMasterData e 
cross apply
(select top 1 CostCenterMain
FROM dbo.CostCenterConsolidatedLkUp
WHERE CostCenterMainNo = e.MasterCCNo
) e
```

Comment: I ran a query for the above and it returned the following.        Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near 'e'.

Comment: @BrianD.Brubaker sorry, Had too much included in my cut and paste. Should be ok now